# Can't push in git, though status tells "up to date"

Tags: git

Git status shows "up to date":

```
[p] vh/prodos3_v3_graphs☰ * 1 ± git status -uno
On branch vh/prodos3_v3_graphs
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/vh/prodos3_v3_graphs'.
nothing to commit (use -u to show untracked files)
```

Nevertheless git push fails:

```
[p] vh/prodos3_v3_graphs☰ * ± git push
Username for 'https://git.42.de': vheinitz
Password for 'https://me@git.42.de': 
To https://git.42.de/repo/prodos3.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
 ! [rejected]        prodos3_v3_developer-all -> prodos3_v3_developer-all (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.42.de/repo/prodos3.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What is the reason?
First of all, why is git mentioning master in the output? I don't want to push in master, have no privileges for this branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have two problems

As for the up-to-date message: You are up to date with your current local remote branch, but not the server remote branch.
Perform a `git pull` to update your local "remote branch" and then perform the push

```
git pull origin prodos3_v3_graphs
```

The other problem is that you are pushing all local branches.
You can specify which branch to push by using `git push <remote> <branch>`, e.g:

```
 git push origin prodos3_v3_graphs
```

Or you can configure git to push to the current branch

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Then perform a `git push`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Great! this helped. The problem seemed to be, that master changed for some reason and should be pulled. I was not aware, that I'm pushing all branches even if Ive checked out one branch.
Checking out master, pulling, pushing and than switching back to my branch helped!

Comment: Good to hear:), you should do the git config command, this makes the git push more obvoius in the future as well, since it is a global config that will affect all your repositories.

Comment: What's a local remote branch vs a server remote branch?

Comment: The local remote branch is the local copy you have of the server branch, it will only be updated when you perform a `git fetch` or `git pull` command. 
Local remote branches are used by git to compare you local branch with the server, but is not updated automatically. See https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches